# c++ win32: basic string handling

Tags: c++, winapi

Just jumped into c++ with win32 in Visual Studio 2012. I am experienced in C and C#, but my c++ is a little lacking. The win32 stuff just seems to take any hint of intuition and throw it into a volcano. So far it's been a pain.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
1) Extract text from a textbox "edit" control
2) Convert this text to an int
3) Form a string using a sprintf type formatter for a double-floating point number
4) Take the resulting string and display it in a different text box.

I've tried several different things I've found on the web, but they all come up short. This is the best I could do:

```
wchar_t buffer[30];
const wchar_t formatString[] = {'%','f','\0'}; //Yes I know this is awful, I don't know how to       convert a string literal into a wchar_t array.

GetWindowText(txtFixedPtToFloatInputHandle, &buffer[0], 15);

//Convert to signed integer
fixedPtValue = _wtoi(&buffer[0]);

//get a float
floatVal = 12.50;

//Use formatter to create a string representation
swprintf(buffer,  30, &formatString[0], floatVal);

SetWindowText(txtFixedPtToFloatOutputHandle, buffer);
```

This is the closest I have come. It's nasty I know, but all other things I've found on the web fell short (LPWSTR, boost::, stdio.h). In this code, all of the buffers get loaded with the correct strings! The problem is that my program closes/exits when the function returns! Any help??

Comment: *"I don't know how to convert a string literal into a wchar_t array."* -- Put an `L` in front of it.  -- `const wchar_t formatString[] = L"%f";`

Comment: Unrelated: Do you like to type =P ? You pass `buffer` to `SetWindowText` as most should, but pass `&buffer[0]` to functions like `GetWindowText`. Not any sort of earth-shattering error; its a style thing only. Both are perfectly valid, and if thats how you just do things so be it. I just found it a little strange it wasn't consistent.

Comment: `The problem is that my program closes/exits when the function returns!` It should'n? It exits normally or with error? If with error, use debugger. If normally, I don't see any reason to post strings code. Do you have `main loop`? BTW, consider reading C++ book, you still writing in C.

Comment: Use [StringCchPrintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647541(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of swprintf().  Make sure you're building with UNICODE on so you're getting wide versions of Get/SetWindowText.  What was your problem with LPWSTR?  It's just a typedef.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Not that it's relevant here, but thought I'd mention that the two methods of passing the array technically mean different things (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/218597).

Comment: @icabod were `&buffer` begin passed, I would concur. As typed parameters `buffer` and `&buffer[0]` reduce to a simple address of the same type:`wchar_t*`. They just get there in different ways. `&buffer` on the other hand, is definitely *not* the same; it is of type `wchar_t (*)[30]` and the only legal reduction without a cast to equivalence with `buffer` and `&buffer[0]` is through the only allowable intermediary: `void*`. Thus why passing all three to a target of a `memcpy` is legitimate, while only the first two reduce correctly to `wcscpy`. [See it live](http://ideone.com/p1ff6Y).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to build an ANSI version and an UNICODE version, you may use the [Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
#include <tchar.h>

_TCHAR EditText[ 32 ];
int cbCopied = GetWindowText( hWndInput, EditText, sizeof( EditText ) / sizeof( _TCHAR ) );
// Eventually use GetLastError if cbCopied == 0

// -1 because the snprint familly functions do not write a 0 if len == count, see docs
size_t cbMaxCarToOutput = ( sizeof( EditText ) / sizeof( _TCHAR ) ) - 1;
_sntprintf( EditText, cbMaxCarToOutput, _TEXT( "%f" ), floatVal );

SetWindowText( hWndInput, EditText );
```